# Database value not populating on button submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When I click the submit button on my form the value of Submit is not displaying and at the same time my input fields at the top are still not autofilling like I'd like them to. I'm also trying to use the eye icon to hide the value on post request and clicking the eye icon will reveal the value on textbox.

index.cshtml

```
@page "{id?}"
@model IndexModel

@{ViewData["Title"] = "Main";}

<div class=" container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h1 class="display-4">@Model.PageTitle</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <form class="mt-0" method="get">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 offset-2" id="DepartmentResult"></div>
                <div class="col-4" id="EmployeeResult"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <form class="mt=0" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-3 col-form-label">Employee Name:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Employee name" asp-for="Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <label class="col-2 offset-3 col-form-label">Department Name:</label>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <input class="form-control" title="Department name" asp-for="DeptName">
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-dark col-1 offset-5" type="submit" id="SubmitBtn" name="SubmitBtn" value="Submit" asp-page-handler="Submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div col-4>
                <br />
                    <div class=" row">
                        <label class="col-6 col-form-label">Social Security #:</label>
                        <div class="col-5">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="OutputSSN" disabled />
                            <i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
            type: "GET",
            data: { value: @Model.Id },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

index.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using PracticeApp.Models;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Namespaces
namespace PracticeApp.Pages
{
    // Classes
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        // Fields
        public CompanyContext _context;

        // Properties
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)] public int Id { get; set; }
        [BindProperty] public string PageTitle { get; set; } = "Employee Check";
        public Employee CheckEmployee { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember] public string Name { get; set; }
        [BindProperty, DataMember] public string DeptName { get; set; }
        public string OutputSSN { get; set; }

        // Constructors
        public IndexModel(CompanyContext context) { _context = context; }

        // Methods
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayDepartment(int value) => Partial("_DisplayDepartmentPartial", _context.Departments.Where(x => x.DepartmentId == value).ToList());
        public PartialViewResult OnGetDisplayEmployee(string value) => Partial("_DisplayEmployeePartial", _context.Employees.Where(x => x.DepartmentName == value).GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName).Select(x => x.First()).ToList());

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSubmit()
        {
            OutputSSN = $"{SubstringCheck(OutputSSN, 3)}-{SubstringCheck(OutputSSN, 3, 2)}-{SubstringCheck(OutputSSN, 5, 4)}";
            return Page();
        }

        public string SubstringCheck(string s, int length)
        {
            int len = s.Length;

            if (len > length)
            {
                len = length;
            }
            return s.Substring(0, len);
        }

        public string SubstringCheck(string s, int b, int length)
        {
            int len = s.Length;

            if (len <= b)
            {
                return s;
            }
            len -= b;

            if (len > length)
            {
                len = length;
            }
            return s.Substring(b, len);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: According to your error message, You can have a look at 
[What is a NullReferenceException  and how do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)?

Comment: "at the same time my input fields at the top are still not autofilling like I'd like them to"  What do you mean about  input fields ?Do you mean autofilling the input "Employee name" and "Department name"?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a `BindProperty` attribute to your `OutputSSN` property, so the posted form value is not being bound to it. That's why you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to access its `Length` property.

```
[BindProperty] public string OutputSSN { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike Brind has said the posted form value is not being bound to it.

First you need to add `[BindProperty]` like this:

```
[BindProperty] public string OutputSSN { get; set; }
```

Besides,

> `<input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="OutputSSN" disabled />`

you set the input `disabled`  , so it will cause form value is not being bound to it too. If you want it  cannot be modified, you can use `readonly`:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="OutputSSN" readonly />
```

> I'm also trying to use the eye icon to hide the value on post request
> and clicking the eye icon will reveal the value on textbox.

Below is a demo about eye icon, you can refer to it, I set the value to OutputSSN to show data , you can use your way:

```
<input class="form-control"  asp-for="OutputSSN"  value="a" type="text" readonly/>
<i  class="far fa-eye" id="toggleOutputSSN" ></i>
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Index?handler=DisplayDepartment",
            type: "GET",
            data: { value:@Model.Id  },
            headers: { RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            success: function(data) { $("#DepartmentResult").html(data); }
        });
        const toggleOutputSSN = document.querySelector('#toggleOutputSSN');
        const OutputSSN = document.querySelector('#OutputSSN');

        toggleOutputSSN.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        // toggle the type attribute
        const type = OutputSSN.getAttribute('type') === 'text' ? 'password'   : 'text';
        OutputSSN.setAttribute('type', type);
        // toggle the eye slash icon
        this.classList.toggle('fa-eye-slash');
    });
        });
</script>
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: none of these suggestions work because when I click the Submot button the value on SSN is being read from the database and should appear hidden with the eye closed. when the eye is clicked the raw value should appear. I have 2 properties one with raw value and one with masked value

Comment: @TheGame1083  these suggestions  is about how to send the form to the controller, that the SSN  value has already been set or text, not about read SSN  from the database. "SSN is being read from the database" How does SSN being read from the database? Could you share your code about that?

Comment: Disregard question, I already got the solution from someone else